# React native inline condition based on calculation at view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to write inline condition based on calculation for percentage in view. here is code

```
 <View>
  <Text>
  sometext +
  {(103 * 50 / 100) > 30 ? 30 : (103 * 50 / 100)}
  </Text>
 </View>
```

so the output should be either 30 or percantage value. but this not working can you please help me for this?

Comment: Do you want to show those values as a text?

Comment: @İlker yes value plus text

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the output with the Text component if you want to show it;

```
        <View>
       {(103 * 50 / 100) > 30 ? <Text>30</Text>  : <Text>(103 * 50 / 100)</Text>}
      </View>
```

Although I'm not sure what you are trying to do since you multiple with 50 and divide with 100, it's basically dividing with 2.

Comment: do you get any error? It seems fine to me